# Define default value for columns in View

Tags: sql

I Have a View in SQL Server, in one column ( data type int64) it returns Null value!
But I want to display Zero in it. How Can I define a default Value for Column in View?

Answer (score 1):

use [isNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) may resolve your issue like as velow

```
CREATE VIEW  dbo.MyView
AS 
SELECT col1, col2, isnull(numriccal3 ,0)
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), or better, [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to return a value instead of a null.

```
SELECT COALESCE(FieldName, 0) AS FieldName
FROM Table
```

Comment: same from my side +1 for using COALESCE